# Lumia-Cyan-Update Tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

Just like the Lumia-Black-Update tag, will it be better to have Lumia-Cyan-Update tag as Official updates have started rolling out globally?

Comment: We already have [tag:8.1] for questions about features introduced that version of the operating system, and [tag:update] for questions about issues updating, so how would you anticipate [tag:lumia-cyan-update] to be used?

Comment: Ok. So lumia-black-update was because it was a version of WP8 OS?

Comment: The black update was an update to 8.0; Cyan update is the initial version of 8.1

Comment: Alright. Thank you :)

Comment: @RowlandShaw You are incorrect, Cyan like all other color based updates before, is Nokia's enhancements on top of the operating system. It is Not a part of them.

Comment: @caschw It is how they are delivering 8.1 though

Comment: @RowlandShaw I have Windows Phone 8.1 with the Black update. Also, non Lumia devices do not recieve the color based updates.

Comment: @caschw In that case, the first candidate for a cyan tag could be: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/5363/106

Comment: Technically, Black was not really an update to 8.0, it was Nokia's add-on to 8.0 GDR3. Likewise, Cyan is Nokia's add-on to 8.1. Since [Cyan brings additional features to 8.1](http://conversations.nokia.com/2014/07/15/lumia-cyan-update), it makes sense to have a separate tag, for questions specifically about those additions and changes that don't apply to vanilla 8.1 (e.g. on other manufacturers' phones).

Comment: @caschw You might be having 8.1 with Black because you have installed the Developers Preview. Once the firmware update is out, you will have the official Cyan update.

Comment: @VivekParekh Only Nokia phones get the "colored" updates